How to Generate Warnings or Errors for Nullable Reference Types from Referenced Libraries in C#?
I am working on a C# project where I have enabled nullable reference types to improve code safety and catch potential null reference exceptions at compile-time. However, my project references another library that does not have nullable reference types enabled.
This situation creates a problem: I can't guarantee that values from the referenced library are non-null, even if they are declared as such. This can lead to null reference exceptions at runtime.
For example:
string varInNullableEnabled = ReferencedProjectWithNullableDisabled.StaticClass.StaticNonNullableString;

Here, varInNullableEnabled can actually be null, even though it's declared as non-nullable.
Is there a way to configure Visual Studio to generate warnings or errors in such cases to ensure I handle potential null values properly?

Are you looking for string? varInNullableEnabled?

"even if they are declared as such": If the class library was not made in a nullable context, then the string was neither declared as nullable nor as not nullable. This distinction does not exist in a non nullable context and every reference type is implicitly possibly nullable even without a ?.
